# Network-wide activity page links comments to answers

Tags: bug, network-profile, recent-activity

(Sorry for the bad title - I couldn't come up with a good one.)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Visit [a user's network-wide activity page](https://stackexchange.com/users/22202197/user17242583?tab=activity)
2. Filter by comments by clicking "comments"
3. Click on a comment
4. **On the destination page, the *answer that the comment was made under* is highlighted, not the comment itself!**