# In the 'Responses' tab on the profile, comments on nomination posts should link to the comment instead of to the nomination post

Tags: feature-request, comments, election, nominations, responses

I received a reply to a comment I posted under a nomination in the current election on Mathematics SE. It shows up in my 'Responses' tab on my profile with the heading '2021 Moderator Election' (followed by the full content of the response).

However, this heading links to the nomination post itself: https://math.stackexchange.com/election/9?tab=nomination#post-4302276

Since permalinks to comments on nomination posts [have now been added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361979/moderator-elections-functionality-voting-ui-commenting-and-flagging), it would be better if the heading linked to the comment itself. So, it would be better if the above link was this one instead: https://math.stackexchange.com/election/9?tab=nomination#comment8965523_4302276

Note that the headings in the 'Responses' tab for comment replies received on posts on the main site *do* link directly to those comments, instead of to the posts under which those comments were made. So, it would be good to have the same behavior for comments on the election page as well.

[image]

---

It has been suggested that my post is a duplicate of [Network-wide activity page links comments to answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372094). But that is about the activity tab on https://stackexchange.com, which is built quite differently from the main sites, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Network-wide activity page links comments to answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372094/network-wide-activity-page-links-comments-to-answers)

Comment: @DavidPostill No, that concerns the activity page on stackexchange.com. This is about the 'responses' tab on the activity page on a specific site.

Comment: These are old enough that's it's OK to re-ask: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135225/missing-links-to-responses-to-comments-on-nomination-posts  links to here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361979/moderator-elections-functionality-voting-ui-commenting-and-flagging - so it was requested long ago, and it's now possible to do, just a matter of this re-request.

Comment: @Rob Yes, it seems that originally the title itself was completely missing. Now the title has been added, but it points to the nomination post instead of the comment.